# Position Vector relative to origin

Tags: java, libgdx

I have a little tech game I am messing around with and I can't figure out the formula to position 1 object given another objects origin.

So I have a Spaceship and a Cannon. I have the game setup to use units, so 1 unit = 16 pixels (pixel art).

Basically my cannon should be placed 0.5625 units on the X and 0 on the Y relative to the origin of the Spaceship, which is located at 0, 0 (bottom left corner).

The cannon should is independent on the angle of the spaceship, it can aim in different directions rather than being fixed to aim the way of the spaceship.

I have it constantly following the cursor, which works fine. Now when I rotate the Spaceship, obviously the origin of the Spaceship is changing in world coordinates, so my formula to place the cannon is all messed up, like so:

```
    protected Vector2 weaponMount = new Vector2();

        weaponMount.set(getBody().getPosition().x + 0.5625f, getBody()
            .getPosition().y);
```

Obviously if I position the ship at a 90° angle, X is going to be different and the cannon would be waaaayyy off the ship. Here is a screenshot example of what I mean:

[image: Spaceship fail]

What would be the formula for this? I have tried using cos/sin but that does not work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
weaponMount.set(0.5625f,0).setAngle(SpaceshipAngle).add(getBody().getPosition());
```

Where SpaceshipAngle is the angle of your Spaceship.

Comment: The sprite rotates around it's owner origin just fine, however the position of the cannon is set to the origin of the spaceship, when the spaceship is changed the world coordinates are changed on the origin, so adding 0.5625 to the X is no longer viable.

Comment: Yes, I think you misunderstand my question. The sprite rotates fine around its own origin, however the cannon does not rotate correctly around its origin, the cannon is supposed to stay where it is regardless of the spaceship angle.

Answer (score 0):

The `origin` of the spaceship is the point, arround which the spaceship will rotate and scale (the `Texture` of it). The `position` instead is always the lower left corner of the `Texture` and does not depend on the rotation.
Your problem is, that your `offset` does not depent on the rotation of your `spaceship`.
To take care about this `rotation` you should store a `Vector2 offset`, which describes your weapons offset (in your case it is a `Vector2(0.5625f, 0)`).
Next store a `float angle` describing your spaceships `rotation`.
Then you can rotate the `offset` by using: `offset.setAngle(rotation)`.
The last thing is to set the weapons `position`. The code for this did not change so much:

```
 weaponMount.set(getBody().getPosition().x + offset.x, getBody()
        .getPosition().y + offset.y);
```